# resize and move canvas contents html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I already measure line tools in canvas. I already can save it using getImageData() and putImageData().

And now my only and last concern is how to resize the line and even move it.

Currently, i have this codes:

```
 $("#myCanvas").mousedown(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("mouseDown");

        if(trigger = "1"){
            $('.draggable').draggable( "disable" );
        }else{
            $('.draggable').draggable("enable");
        }       

        var angx=startX;
        var angy=startY;
        startX=(event.clientX-$(canvas).offset().left)*(parseInt($(canvas).attr("width"))/parseInt($(canvas).css("width")));
        startY=(event.clientY-$(canvas).offset().top)*(parseInt($(canvas).attr("height"))/parseInt($(canvas).css("height")));
        //alert(startX + " : " + startY );

        tmp = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);                                    

        $("#myCanvas").bind('mousemove', function(e){       
        endX=(e.clientX-$(canvas).offset().left)*(parseInt($(canvas).attr("width"))/parseInt($(canvas).css("width")));      
        endY=(e.clientY-$(canvas).offset().top)*(parseInt($(canvas).attr("height"))/parseInt($(canvas).css("height"))); 

        drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);   

        });             
 }).mouseup(function(data){
        totalOffsetX = 0, totalOffsetY = 0;     
        $(this).removeClass("mouseDown");
        if(trigger = "1"){
            $('.draggable').draggable( "disable" );
        }else{
        $('.draggable').draggable("enable");
            }   
        $(this).unbind('mousemove');    
        tmp = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);    
});                                 


var Calculate={
    lineLength:function(x1, y1, x2,y2){    
        console.log(x1 + ", "+ y1 +", " + x2 + ", " + y2);
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2*dry-x1*dry, 2)+Math.pow(y2*drx-y1*drx, 2));
    }
}                                                                           

function drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY){                                          
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                                           
    ctx.putImageData(tmp, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();                                                                                        
    ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX,endY);
    ctx.fillStyle="#A9F5F2";
    ctx.font='12pt Calibri';
    //ctx.fillText("Start X: " + startX + " " + " Y: " + startY , startX, startY-10);
    //ctx.fillText("End X: " + endX + " " + " Y: " + endY, endX, endY+10);
    var px =Calculate.lineLength(startX, startY, endX, endY).toFixed(1);    
    ctx.fillText(Math.round(px/1)+"px" ,endX,endY);     
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#00FFFF';                                                                                
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();                                            

        }
```

Comment: What is draggable function?

Comment: Its not totally part for canvas measurement, its included in jquery library. Its adding "draggable" class in your element so you can drag it anywahere. Any idea about my problem?\

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I dont think i can create one, since the image and functions i used have dependencies. Lot of code to re-arrange. Do you have any experience about it? Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking--at least to me. :-/  In general, you can (1) Clear the canvas, (2) `context.scale(scaleFactorX,scaleFactorY)` and (3) redraw the canvas content.  You canvas content will be scaled by the specified scaleFactors.

Comment: Heres the fiddle of the current work done. Please help ! Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/oggLnyop/3/